# NetApp Data ONTAP PowerShell Get Access-Based Enumeration (ABE) Flag?

Tags: powershell, file-sharing, cifs, netapp

I am trying to find out what CIF Shares have the Access-Based Enumeration (ABE) flag set on them through the NetApp Data ONTAP PowerShell CMDLET. You can set it through the CLI by using

```
controller> cifs shares -change sharename -accessbasedenum
```

I am looking for the PowerShell equivalent if possible! Thanks!

Comment: I'm really no PowerShell expert but I found this link that may help you along a bit; https://communities.netapp.com/message/100055#100055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the status of ABE on the shares

```
Connect-NAController <VfilerName>
Get-NaCifsShare | ft ShareName,IsAccessBasedEnum
```

and to set ABE for a specific share

```
Connect-NAController <VfilerName>
Set-NACifsShare -Share <Share_Name> -AccessBasedEnum $true
```

you can use the `Get-Help` CMDlet to get information on any of the DataOntap API commands.

Comment: I actually found the same link as @Chopper3 and verified that these commands/properties exist. I'm using version 2.4. You can check your version with `Get-Module DataOntap | fl`